# set conditional price in woocommerce with gravity forms without using GP conditional pricing plugin

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, gravity-forms-plugin

Please help me for solve this issues

Thanks in advance

i am using woocommerce with gravity forms add-on in ecommerce web developing. Gravity Forms gives by default facility to set option price for woo-commerce product
Now I want to set conditional pricing in woocommerce gravity forms. but gravity forms cant itself, for this we have to install the GP CONDITIONAL PRICING plugin for using this plugin we can set conditional pricing based on user input in woocommerce product. but it has some limitation. I want to set conditional pricing without using GP CONDITIONAL PRICING plugin.

Please, help me who knows about gravity forms, woocommerce, conditional pricing. Is there any hook or filter that we can put in function.php file? Kindly suggest me right solution

check this following link

[Gravity Forms][1]

[Gravity Forms Woocommerce Add-on](https://www.woothemes.com/products/gravity-forms-add-ons/)

[GP Condiional Pricing plugin - we don't want to use it](https://gravitywiz.com/documentation/gp-conditional-pricing/)

Comment: Hi Krish, what limitations does GP Conditional Pricing have for your desired use-case?

Comment: Limitations, (1) like we can not use multiple values of one field in condition set for same price. (2) We can not use OR and AND condition in set. Now we can set either All (means AND conditions for all fields of set) or Any (means OR conditions for all fields of set).